# Send ERC20 Tokens directly to contract address to trigger to function in contract

Tags: erc-20, erc-20-approve, transferfrom, receive

We are trying to bypass allow method and make the contract more UX friendly. And instead of first allowing contract to spend and after calling transferFrom method, we are thinking about just sending ERC20 tokens directly to a contract and triggering function for example to change the state of the contract from deployed to ready ( as per our project)

Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible (but I'm not sure if it has some problem or is safe). After sending the tokens, you need someone to trigger a new tx to call the function that checks if the contract has enough balance and then does the changes (you need ofc the address of the erc20 contract).
   If the erc20 Contract is yours, then check this Standard (but still in Draft and maybe there is better Standard to solve that problem) https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard 
  Anyway, Token integration is very risky so take care https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GaCt_lM_ak

Comment: It is not possible under the ERC-20 standard, [EIP-777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777), [EIP-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155). There's [EIP-2612](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612) that proposes an extension to ERC-20 that allows using a single call to replace approve+transfer.

Comment: Perhaps reversing your logic the other way around (ie calling a function in your contract that will call transferFrom) might solve it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions I see for your problem is implement a event listener in Js that will listen for income ERC20 transfers and call the appropriate method on receive with the sender address in argument.

The con of if is you will pay all gas fees because it will be your address that will call the contract.